# Final Line of a Text File is Printed Twice

Tags: c, file-io

Assume FILE_NAME is a global constant,

If I have the following code

```
FILE *file;
file = fopen(FILE_NAME, "r");
char string[30];
do
{
    fgets(string, 30, file);
    printf("%s", string);
}
while ( !feof(file) );
```

It prints all the lines in the txt file but the last one is printed twice. How do I prevent it from printing twice?

Comment: [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your loop to:

```
while ( fgets(string, 30, file) != NULL ) {
    printf("%s", string);
}
```

`fgets()` will fail and return `NULL` before `feof(file)` becomes true, and it won't update `string`. So right now you're successfully calling `fgets()` on the last line, printing it, unsuccessfully calling `fgets()`, printing the last line again, then terminating your loop.

The key thing to understand here is that you only know you're at the end of the file when you've tried to read from it and your read has failed. Until then, someone might have appended data to the end of the file since the last time you read it, for all you know, for example.